# ERROR: Could not detect node name from path or package

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm

I wanted do make a TF2 trading bot and wanted to install the module "steam_user"
`C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Desktop\bot>npm install steam-user`
but when I hit enter this comes up:

```
npm ERR! could not detect node name from path or package

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-15T16_40_36_775Z-debug.log

I don't really know how to solve this problem :(

Greetings
Dogeman
```

Comment: Can you show the completed log? That would be easy to understand the exact issue.

Comment: I solved this problem! I just created a package.json file and typed `npm i steam-user` I logged in and put my Authenticator Code in and it's done now